# How do i compute the sum n+n/2+n/3+n/4........+(n/n) in less than O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm, series

I need an algorithm that has time complexity less than O(n).

Currently I have this algorithm:

`int n;
         sum=n;
         for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
         {
         sum+=n/i;
         }`

Comment: If you have plenty of memory you could always precompute or cache the results in an array

Comment: (on unrelated questions, your code is incorrect right now : n is uninitialized)

Comment: Also: using the `int` datatype will cause all fractions to be lost.

Comment: This is part of the "COOLGUYS" question on codechefs monthly contest! I suggest you wait until AFTER the competition where they will provide you an editorial.

Comment: :) ok i'll try till the end

Comment: Do you want integer division or floating-point division?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck thats all taken care of

Answer (score 2):

That's n * (1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + .. + 1/n)

The latter sum is the nth harmonic number, and has a relatively good [approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Rate_of_divergence).

Check it with a large `n` to see whether it's precise enough for you - obviously for small `n`s simply use your "algorithm" or a lookup table.

```
import math

euler=0.5772156649015
sum=0
show=10
for i in range(1,1000001):
    sum += 1.0/i
    if i == show:
        approx = math.log(i) + euler + 1.0/(2*i)
        print "%7d %.2e" % (i, approx - sum)
        show *= 10

     10 8.33e-04
    100 8.33e-06
   1000 8.33e-08
  10000 8.33e-10
 100000 8.45e-12
1000000 9.93e-13
```

Comment: Is this really a correct answer considering the OP wants to use integer division?